# Dimensional Variables

Tags: fortran

I'm writing a program for school in FORTRAN. We have to write a program where the user enters a number of grades. With that number of grades, I have to make the program prompt the user that many times to enter the grades. I think I would use a dimensional variable, but I don't know how.

So far I have this, with obvious compiling errors:

```
INTEGER :: NumGrades
REAL :: GradeAverage
INTEGER :: N

WRITE (*,*) 'Enter Number of grades: '
READ (*,*) NumGrades
N = NumGrades

REAL, Dimension(N) :: Grade

WRITE (*,*) 'Enter the individual grades: '
READ (*,*) Grade
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since it's homework, hints only: (i) make `grade` an `allocatable` array; (ii) you'll need a `do` loop to read `numgrades` grades.  Also, you don't need both `n` and `numgrades`, you can just `read(*,*) numgrades` directly.

Comment: Note also that what you call "dimensional variable" is properly called an [array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your assignment isn't overdue, you could use allocation. It essentially lets you give an array size after initializing your variables.

```
INTEGER :: NumGrades
REAL :: GradeAverage !Not exactly sure what this is used for in this snippet
REAL, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: Grade
INTEGER :: i !Used for loop counters    

WRITE (*,*) 'Enter Number of grades: '
READ (*,*) NumGrades

allocate(Grade(NumGrades)) !size(Grade) == NumGrades or whatever you inputted

WRITE (*,*) 'Enter the individual grades: '
!DO i = 1, NumGrades
    READ(*, *) Grade(i)
!END DO

GradeAverage = sum(Grade) / size(Grade) !Just thought I'd throw this in
```

The dimension(:) lets the computer know that there is no defined size yet.

Alternatively, you can set the array size to a max integer value if you don't care about memory constraints.

Hope you got this for your assignment!

Edit - Oh yeah, don't forget to deallocate(Grade).